# Python: Extend function if CL argument was entered

Tags: python, if-statement, command-line-arguments

Basically, I want to print out part of the command output only if "-v" was entered, without doing second function with more variables.

```
def ldaptst(host):
  for LDAPIP in getLDAPIPs():
    global vlan
    global admip

    ldaptst_output = os.popen("ldaptst -vvvv -s " + LDAPIP + " -n " + host).read ().split ('\n')
    for entry in ldaptst_output:
      if "VLAN" in entry:
        vlan = entry.split(": ")[1]
      if "iphostnumber[0]" in entry:
        admip = entry.split("=")[1]
    if vlan != "vlan":
      print "VLAN \t\t\t: " + vlan
    if sys.argv[1] == "-v":
      if admip != "admin IPv6":
        print "ADM IPv6 Address \t: " + admip
    print ""
    break


if __name__ == "__main__":
  signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, signalHandler)
  if len (sys.argv) == 1:
    print "No free rides, enter hostname!"
  elif len (sys.argv) >= 3 and sys.argv[1] == "-v":
    hosts = sys.argv[2:]
    for host in hosts:
      if len(host) != 14:
        print "Host should have 14 characters."
      else:
        ldaptst(host)
  else:
    hosts = sys.argv[1:]
    for host in hosts:
      if len(host) != 14:
        print "Host should have 14 characters."
      else:
        ldaptst(host)
```

Needless to say, this `if sys.argv[1] == "-v":` doesn't work. Do you have any suggestions how do this the elegant way?

Comment: https://docs.python.org/2/library/argparse.html?highlight=argparse#argparse?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the problem. Actually, `if sys.argv[1] == "-v":` does work, the issue was typo in variables.